# jquery rearranging page elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, coffeescript

I have a body of text which is about 12 paragraphs long... inside the text are a couple of blockquotes which I would like to automatically highlight and rearrange throughout the document (every 3rd paragraph) and afterwards removing the blockquote so that the text appears twice.  Once as a highlighted snippet in an automatically ordered position, and second in the original location without the block...

It sort of works, but I feel like I'm missing something because it doesn't follow the order. I would think it'd be (3,6,9, etc.) but it seems to be thrown off by something?

```
jQuery ->
    content = $('article.city-review div')
    content.find('blockquote').each (index) ->
        line_space = (index+1)*3
        quote_tag = '<span class=\"quote_left\">'+$(this).text()+'</span>'
        content.find('p:nth-child('+line_space+')').prepend(quote_tag)
        $(this).contents().unwrap().wrap('<p></p>')
```

UPDATE:

Input looks like:

```
<p>Text</p>
<p>More Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>More Text</p>
<blockquote>Text</blockquote>
<p>Text</p>
<p>More Text</p>
<blockquote><p>Sometimes these appear</p></blockquote>
```

The output gives me empty p tags `<p></p>` and nested p tags `<p><p>Something</p></p>`

Comment: can you be more specific about what is throw off? Where are the blockquotes appearing right now? after 2,5,8 or not at all, etc?

Comment: it's inserting it almost right after the other, because I'm getting left over empty p tags and then nested p tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery ->
    content = $('article.city-review div')
    content.find('blockquote').each (index) ->
        position = [2,6,10]
        line_space = position[index]
        text = $(this).text()
        quote_tag = '<span class=\"quote_left\">'+text+'</span>'
        content.find('p:nth-child('+line_space+')').after(quote_tag)
        $(this).replaceWith('<p>'+text+'</p>')
```

Making an array is an easy way to test out the spacing and unless you need an unlimited length could work.  Remove the unwrap and use `replacewith`, maybe simpler for you and `after` instead of `prepend` unless you want the new quotes inside another tag.